# Hover Effects for Wordpress Cards

Tags: css, wordpress, hover

I am working on a wordpress website, with the Avada theme. I have created these cards for events. The client wants the hover effects for this card for the text to turn white while the two container backgrounds change to two different colors.

What is the best way to do this via CSS?

What I have currently in the non-hover design
[Current Non-Hover Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8mh1.png)

What the client wants on hover (Via Design)
[Hover Effect Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKpUL.png)

I have tried to custom code it myself without success. I have attached an example of trying to change the font color on hover but it hasn't worked

```
.event-card-container:hover {
    color:#ffffff !important;
    
}
```

Comment: We'll need to see some HTML code as well in order to be able to help out. CSS code alone isn't enough (and even the CSS code you've shared isn't sufficient, please share everything needed to reproduce this layout).